# Run exe file added as resource in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

Plainly put, I have added as a resource to a visual studio project an exe file. How do I run this file? I'm coding in c#.

Comment: What kind of exe is it? Is it managed or just native?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take Resource as byte[]

```
byte[] myResBytes = ...;
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(myResBytes);
// search for the Entry Point
MethodInfo method = asm.EntryPoint;
if(method == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
// create an instance of the Startup form Main method
object o = asm.CreateInstance(method.Name);
// invoke the application starting point
method.Invoke(o, null);
```

Also see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13897/Load-an-EXE-File-and-Run-It-from-Memory) for more details

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You..!! Though I had seen that link earlier you put it in the right perspective.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the file being executed is a .net executable or a win32 executable? Any limitations as far as a 32 bit executable invoking a 64 bit executable? And vise versa?

Comment: I don't think it does... give a try

Answer (score 0):

You must use Process.Start method. See it in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Process.Start cannot be used to run resource files